# python (on Windows OS) - Facebook app with Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook

I have a problem and so confused about it.
I created an application and uploaded it to Google app engine and works fine.
Then i wanted to connect it to a Facebook application, so i created the Facebook application and added the Google app engine URL in the Facebook Canvas and it also works quiet well.

The problem is that, now i need to make sure the user is logged in and that he authorized my application. After a lot of search i ended up with nothing.
I found Django framework - PyFacebook and other stuff too that i don know what do i need to setup ?????

I am working on Windows and with Python

So if anyone can point me to the way "with details, please"
What do i need to install and what frameworks, SDKs ... i need ?

Thanks in advance ,

Samer Samy

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't the facebook "engine" just a API? a HTTP based GET/POST system that returns a map of data? just like the Twitter API? If so, use a socket and some common protocol parsing, i'd use Twisted if i were you to jumpstart things: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Comment: @Torxed: neither sockets nor a lot of the other stuff Twisted does will work on App Engine at all.

Comment: @Samer: if you're using App Engine, your python scripts are not running on Windows.

Comment: @Wooble: Sure enough the App Engine has emptied out the socket library but has included WebOb instead: http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @Torxed: webob does nothing like what either Twisted or socket do; external connections are made with the urlfetch API.

Comment: @Wooble: Thanks for the tip, i really got confused ... it is my first time to use Google App Engine

Answer (score 0):

The official python facebook app I know is https://github.com/facebook/runwithfriends
If you look through it most if not all about facebook python app is there.

Comment: yes, i am finally struggling through and i think it is the best way to get start, thanks